# construct a sequence of random orthogonal matrices in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra

construct a sequence of random orthogonal matrices in Julia

It is possible to construct ONE random orthogonal via the qr-decomposition just as in matlab in this way:

A = rand(n,n)

Q, R = qr(A).

However, how would one construct say 50 or 100 orthogonal random matrices?

Comment: Am I missing something about this question. Wouldn't you just do the same thing in a loop or a comprehension?

Comment: The required distribution of matrices is also important. Since there are many orthogonal (unitary) matrices, a natural desire is to have the probability of each matrix the same. Defining this "the same" is a little tricky, and the solution is usually to use what is called the Haar measure, or in plain english: make the probabilities invariant to rotations of the relevant space. If this sounds too nit picky, the best way is to find a library of routines which already takes this into account and use it (e.g. RandomMatrices package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an array comprehension that generates 100 orthogonal 5x5 matrices:

```
orthogonalize(X::AbstractMatrix) = copy(qr(X).Q)

Qs = [orthogonalize(randn(5, 5)) for _=1:100]
```

You can check that they're all orthogonal:

```
julia> all(Q'Q ≈ I for Q in Qs)
true
```

If you want to generate random unitary matrices, you can do this:

```
Qs = [orthogonalize(randn(5, 5) + randn(5, 5)*im) for _=1:100]
```

#### On Distribution

@Dan_Getz rightly brought up the issue of distribution of the generated orthogonal matrices. The problem is that taking a matrix generated by `rand(n, n)` and then orthogonalizing it is likely to favor some matrices in the full space of orthgonal matrices over others. The problem is that generating a matrix that has all entries in [0, 1] means you start a very specific region of the space of possible matrices. When you orthogonalize, the orthogonal matrix you get is also likely to be biased. The only way this might not be the case is if there's some theorem that tells us that orthogonalizing a matrix with [0, 1] entires is equally likely to generate all orthogonal matrices, but I really doubt such a theorem is true.

Using `randn(n, n)` to generate a random matrix is much less likely to have this problem because every "orientation" of matrix is equally likely. It's still possible that orthogalization introduces some bias in orientation of the output, but that's less likely. Accordingly, in the code above I changed `rand` to `randn` to produce randonly oriented matrices.

There might still be distribution issues if you want code that samples uniformly from all orthogonal matrices. It's not entirely obvious that this is even possible. For example, it's not possible to uniformly sample from all real numbers because there's no uniform measure on the reals. However, [O(n) is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18653/compactness-of-the-set-of-n-times-n-orthogonal-matrices) so it seems likely to be possible, just as it is possible to sample uniformly from the unit interval. But that doesn't mean that the output of the QR orthogonalization procedure covers all of O(n) uniformly. As Dan suggested, you could use the [RandomMatrices](https://github.com/JuliaMath/RandomMatrices.jl) package to generate random matrices with a known distribution in a disciplined way.

Matlab would have the same issue if using the same method to generate orthogonal matrices.

Comment: What's the point of `copy` there? 

Comment: My worry is about the distribution of these matrices. It needs justification if claimed to be uniform (Haar measure). And if Uniform is not needed... well... just a copy of a single orthogonal matrix is also a sequence ;). Okay, powers of an orthogonal matrix are also orthogonal (if you don't want to notice immediately).

Comment: The copy converts from the lazy QR factor type to a regular matrix. I have no idea about the distribution; I’m just showing how to do what the OP showed repeatedly. Note that the question doesn’t say anything about what distribution the matrices should have and if this is problematic for 100 then it has the same problem for one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you know if this is possible to do for unitary matrices as well?

Comment: @Dan getz what do you mean about the distribution? In Matlab they have the randstream for example to produce a sequence of matrices, is this related to distribution in Julia ?

Comment: May I ask you, what is this line doing: copy(qr(X).Q)

Comment: As I wrote before: "The copy converts from the lazy QR factor type to a regular matrix."

Comment: all(conj(Q')Q ≈ I for Q in Qs) returns FALSE

Comment: Using `randn` seems to solve the uniformity problem. This is my proof sketch/intution: Take an IID matrix of normals, and rotate it i.e. M -> R*M*R' , then looking at R*M, you get linear combs of normals which are also normal. Additionally, their variances are same. They can lose independence, but orthogonal combs of normals, are independent (another special prop of normals). Do it again with R' and you get back a uniform IID normals matrix, which means, unless `qr` introduces asymmetries, the probs are invariant to O(n). Google will give a proper proof (but tried to manage 10mins without it).

Comment: @user21369645, the `'` operator computes the conjugate transpose, so you're conjugating twice (this is also the case in Matlab)

Comment: Ohh my mistake I meant to say: conj(Q)*Q==I : FALSE

Comment: conj(Q)*Q isn't a meaningful operation. You're conjugating each element of the matrix, not transposing it, and then multiplying it by itself. To check if a complex matrix is unitary check if Q'Q is approximately I.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer:

```
Q = [rand(Haar(1),2)  for _ = 1:n]
```

Comment: What is `Haar` and where does it come from?

Comment: I believe this is what Dan Getz was talking about in his previous comment. It is from the library "RandomMatrices.jl".